# Change Flutter Icon From (title?) bar (not App bar)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Image worth 1000 words :

[image]

Apologies for typos in Screenshot!!

How to Change this Icon?
Thankyou.

Comment: share the code how you implemented it. So that we can answer.

Comment: @dhuna1981 it is just hello world app with appbar title changed.

Comment: I believe the Android Framework automatically uses the Launcher icon for this. Can you reference any app where this icon doesn't equal the Launcher icon?

Comment: @Marcel i didn't find any app the way you asked, but i believe flutter will definitely have option for this. Can you tell me name of that icon/ like what is called in that title bar, how should i google for it?

Comment: I did a quick googling for "android app switcher icon", see my answer below.

Comment: @krupeshAnadkat You can take a look at this Medium article about this subject: [https://medium.com/glottery/taskdescription-customization-with-flutter-17d7a1067649](https://medium.com/glottery/taskdescription-customization-with-flutter-17d7a1067649)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to customize that icon using Android's TaskDescription API.
In [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383641/can-i-set-a-different-icon-for-the-android-task-switcher) there's an explanation on how to do it on the Android side.

However, I don't think there's a Flutter package for that yet.
Feel free to create one and submit it to the [Dart Pub](https://pub.dartlang.org).